# Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone 8 - where is it?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-express, visual-studio-2012

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fda2bad5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) refer to 3 flavors of Visual Studio Express 2012:

> "This includes Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8, Visual Studio
>   Express 2012 for Windows Phone 7, and Visual Studio Express 2012 for
>   Web."

<del>However I can't find any other reference or download link to **Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone 8**. Does anybody know?</del>

**UPDATE**:
[Windows Phone SDK 8.0](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk) and [Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=269891) releases have been announced on Oct 30 2012 in the [Build](http://www.buildwindows.com/) conference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone is now available and you can download it from [here](http://aka.ms/JenVS2012).  Scroll down to the "Visual Studio Express 2012" section and expand the node for "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone".

UPDATE: you can now find Visual Studio Express 2012 downloads here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/Results.aspx?q=visual%20studio%20express%202012&form=DLC

Comment: Express 2012 is no longer listed on that web page

Comment: Yeah ! It is no longer there. Any other suggestion for a download?

Comment: Okay ! I downloaded the installer from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30664 . Hope it'll work !

Answer (score 9):

According to http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/products/express they will be available as soon as the product group for Windows Phone will release again a newer version of the SDK (probably a major release).

Comment: Anything new here? I can't find any info on whether the SDK is already available, but I'm not sure whether I'm just lame or there isn't anything new out there yet.

Comment: The next new version will be 7.8 and 8 SDK. It's not too long until it will be available to internet sources (which should be taken with a fair amount of grain). But until now, there is nothing new.